# ?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'main' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error when running `python manage.py runserver`

> ?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'main' isn't unique. You may not be able
>   to reverse all URLs in this namespace

## mysite/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', include('main.urls')),
]
```

## main/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blog, name='blog'),
    path("about/", views.about, name="about"),
]
```

Comment: Why have you included main.urls twice?

Comment: In addition to what @DanielRoseman said, you don't need `app_name = 'main'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`path('', include('main.urls'))` means that all of the url patterns from `main` will be included without any additional prefix.

`path('asdf/', include('main.urls'))` would mean that all of the url patterns from `main` will be included with additional `asdf/` prefix, so root index url would become `asdf/` and `about/` would become `asdf/about/` (in your case - `about/about/`).

If you'd have 100500 url patterns in main.urls you'd still need to include them only once.

Answer (score 0):

simply change:

`path('', include('main.urls'))`
**to**
`path('', include('main.urls', namespace='default'))`