# django home page path not found

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFMow.png)django stopped showing me the admin page
so i used "make migrations" it worked
now it won't show me a "hello world" page
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
     return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
     from . import views

     urlpatterns = [
        path("",views.index,name="home"),
      ]
```

urls.py for the app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path("products/",include('products.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmfxK.png)

Comment: you are missing the final path in your urls.py

Comment: **path("",views.index,name="home"),** is not your apps urls ???

Comment: maybe change `path("products/",include('products.urls')),` to `path("",include('products.urls')),`

Comment: thanks guys i unistalled django and installed it again and now it works

Comment: @md5diablo glad you found the solution but I can guarantee you that's not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'main' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807808/urls-w005-url-namespace-main-isnt-unique-you-may-not-be-able-to-reverse)