# Django project Page not Found

Tags: django, url-routing

I am trying the basic Django tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/

The admin page is up and running but getting a 404 on the http://localhost:8000/polls/ page:

I cannot understand what this code is doing:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

I didn't define any `polls.urls`, so how will it know how to route the request?
Total beginner here. Coming from the old Tomcat/JBoss world.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'main' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807808/urls-w005-url-namespace-main-isnt-unique-you-may-not-be-able-to-reverse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'polls.urls'` means `polls/urls.py`, i.e. you need to have a `urls.py` in the `polls` app folder.

The previous step in that tutorial asks you to create one:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view

> In the `polls/urls.py` file include the following code:
>
> ```
> from django.urls import path
>
> from . import views
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('', views.index, name='index'),
> ]
> ```

The URL dispatcher then will concatenate the path in your main `urls.py` (`'polls/'`) and the one in the `polls/urls.py` (`''`) to resolve the view name (`views.index`).