# How to retrive image from django database?

Tags: django, django-models

I saved image in database, there are multiple images and i want to retrive it in my website.

my image is stored in static folder inside app folder that is card/static/images.

my images is showing when i enter link http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/p.jpeg

this is my urls.py
`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('card.urls')),
    path('index/', include('card.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`this is my models.py`

```
class dish(models.Model):
    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dish_size = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    dish_price = models.IntegerField()
    dish_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dish_image = models.ImageField()
    dish_date = models.DateField()
```

`this is my index.html file`

```
<img src="{{ request.dish.dish_image.url }}" height="100px" width="100px">
```

`this is my setting.py`

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'images/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'card/static/images')
```

`
this is my card/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('/', views.index),
    path('/index', views.index),
    path('index/', views.index),
    path('index', views.index),
]
```

this is my views file

```
def index(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    dish_name = request.POST.get('dish_name')
    dish_size = request.POST.get('dish_size')
    dish_price = request.POST.get('dish_price')
    dish_description = request.POST.get('dish_description')
    dish_image = request.POST.get('dish_image')
    item = dish(dish_name = dish_name, dish_size = dish_size, dish_price = dish_price, dish_description = dish_description, dish_image = dish_image, dish_date = datetime.today()) 
    item.save()
return render(request, "card/index.html")
```

Comment: show card/urls.py file and the `index` view code

Comment: okay, i edited it added , please check ones

Comment: double include in main urls.py is not needed also please take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807808/urls-w005-url-namespace-main-isnt-unique-you-may-not-be-able-to-reverse/56808194#56808194

Comment: urlpatterns diversity in cards/urls.py has no effect, django can handle leading/trailing slashes automatically. "index" page usually means root URL without `/index/` path so please choose something specific whether it is `/index/` or `/` root page. To get `dishes` in a template you must return them via `context` which is described in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) and can be [found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bdjango-templates%5d%20render%20context) using search.

Comment: You need `else` block after `if request.method == "POST":` to handle `GET` requests and prepare data for the template.