# Django not recognizing my url, cannot get into the app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

i am very new to Django, just trying out with a url to a view
structure basically this:

```
test\
    project-level files + templates
newyear\
    app files + templates
manage.py
```

on newyear urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

on views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'newyear/index.html', {
        "newyear": now.month == 1 and now.day == 1  
    })
```

on urls.py in test

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('newyear/', include('newyear.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

on settings in test

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'newyear',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I have rerun the server but still only recognizes /admin, please help thanks

Comment: We don't know what "can't get into the app" actually means.  If you're getting errors, or seeing unexpected results, please post those.

Comment: I gues this is your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807808/urls-w005-url-namespace-main-isnt-unique-you-may-not-be-able-to-reverse/56808194#56808194

Answer (score 1):

You may have to set your `app_name` in your newyear urls.py. it should look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "newyear"   #set this
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your website via `http://localhost/newyear`

This is because of your urlpatterns in `urls.py`.
The include function appends all urls from the given list and appends them unto the original name.

To fix this just remove `newyear/` in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('newyear.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), ]
```